# Use system2 with an argument containing an ampersand (&)

Tags: r, command-line

I want to run something like

```
stat --format '%m' $file
```

from R. So I translated this to

```
system2("stat", args = c("--format", "'%m'", file)),
        stdout = TRUE)
```

This works fine unless the file name contains an ampersand. In that case it seems to be interpreted as a redirect. How can I escape the ampersand (&)?

Comment: Does wrapping it in `shQuote` fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, it did work: I had a chmod later in my function that also needed to be quoted. Gave the same error message. You could put it as an answer or I can self-answer if you don't feel like it.

Comment: Go ahead and self-answer. You can provide more details about what worked for your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the arguments contains special characters they need to be quoted, so the correct way to call `system2` in this case is

```
system2("stat", args = c("--format", "'%m'", shQuote(file)), 
        stdout = TRUE)
```

If you read the help to quickly you might think that all arguments are quoted but note that it states:

> Unlike ‘system’, ‘command’ is always quoted by ‘shQuote’, so it  must be a single command without arguments.

That is, arguments are not `shQuote`'d by default.

## Security

Be careful when you can't trust your input, a malicious user could provide the following value for file:

```
file <- "foo&touch foo"
```

to

```
system2("stat", args = c("--format", "'%m'", file),
        stdout = TRUE)
```

which would create a file `foo` in your working directory. It could also do something more evil, *not* good.